# How to run button submit type on mvc view programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the view I've written the following code for search Action.
I want to automatically run the search Button once for the first time the View Page loads ...
In fact, what is the solution to run this Button at runtime without user clicks?

```
Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Brand", FormMethod.Post, New AjaxOptions With {
                                        .InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        .UpdateTargetId = "GridList"}))
@Html.TextBox("strName", Nothing, New With {.class = "form-control", .PlaceHolder = "XXXXX"})
<button type="submit" style="display: none">Search</button>
```

End Using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the submit button click using JavaScript.

Give an Id to the button

```
<button type="submit" style="display: none" id="btn-search">Search</button>
```

and now in `document.ready` event, you may trigger the click event

```
$(function () {

    $("#btn-search").trigger("click");

})
```

Another option is to trigger the form `submit` event using JavaScript.

Here I am using jQuery. But you can do the same thing with vanilla JavaScript as well.

EDIT: As per the question in the comment

> How should I put a condition to run only once. For example, if the
>   user clicks on the Search button, and the information is Filtered and
>   Loaded to the view, does not run this trigger?

You can use a flag variable in your to control this.  Specify a JavaScript method as the `OnBegin` property value of your `AjaxOptions`. This method will be called before the ajax call is made. Based on your flag variable value you can return true or false. When this method returns `false`, the ajax call will not be made.

Here is a quick example.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Brand",
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            OnBegin = "searchAjaxBegin",
                            UpdateTargetId = "GridList"
                        }))
{
    <input type="text" name="query" value="" />
    <button type="submit" id="btn-search">Search</button>
}
```

and in your JavaScript

```
<script>

    var searchCallMade = false;

    function searchAjaxBegin() {
        if (searchCallMade) {
            console.log('Will not proceed with AJAX call');
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(function () {

        $("#btn-search").trigger("click");
        searchCallMade = true;

    })

</script>
```

If you want more control over how your Ajax call is made, you may also consider ditching the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper and write code to handle the form submit event and make the ajax call yourself.

Comment: How should I put a condition to run only once. For example, if the user clicks on the Search button, and the information is Filtered and Loaded to the view, does not run this trigger?

Comment: You can use the `OnBegin` event for that. See the update posted.

Comment: I added the code, but it does not run at the first time, Please see the contents of my view:

Answer (score 0):

I added the code, but btn-search not run at first view page loading
Please see the contents of my view:

```html
<section class="panel">
    <header Class="panel-heading tab-bg-dark-navy-blue">
        <label class="bg-transparent wht-color">اطلاعات جامع ماشین آلات</label>
    </header>

    <div class="panel-body  pull-left">
        @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "MachinInfo", FormMethod.Post, New AjaxOptions With {
                                                                    .InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                                    .OnBegin = "searchAjaxBegin",
                                                                    .UpdateTargetId = "GridList"}))

            @Html.DropDownList("DDSearchItems", New SelectListItem() {
                     New SelectListItem With {.Text = "نوع", .Value = "MachinName"},
                     New SelectListItem With {.Text = "برند", .Value = "BrandName"},
                         New SelectListItem With {.Text = "تیپ", .Value = "MachinTypeName"},
                         New SelectListItem With {.Text = "پلاک", .Value = "NPlate"},
                         New SelectListItem With {.Text = "کد سازمانی", .Value = "OrgCode"},
                         New SelectListItem With {.Text = "محل استقرار", .Value = "Mcamp"},
                         New SelectListItem With {.Text = "سریال کارت", .Value = "CardSerial"},
                         New SelectListItem With {.Text = "VIN", .Value = "VIN"}}, "جستجو در همه ستونها",
                 htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "btn btn-white btn-sm"})

            @Html.TextBox("strName", Nothing, New With {.class = "btn btn-white btn-sm", .PlaceHolder = "متن جستجو"})
            @<button type="submit" id="btn-search" value="" Class="glyphicon glyphicon-search btn btn-default" />
        End Using
    </div>


    <div id="GridList">
        @Html.Partial("_PVMachinInfoGrid")
    </div>

</section>

<div Class="pull-left btn-toolbar">
    <div Class="btn btn-default">
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "MachinInfoAdd", Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn btn-small", .data_toggle = "tooltip", .data_placement = "top", .title = "اضافه کردن سطر جدید"})
    </div>
    @*<div Class="btn btn-default">
            @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "glyphicon glyphicon-tasks btn btn-small", .data_toggle = "tooltip", .data_placement = "top", .title = "لیست برندها"})
        </div>*@
</div>


<script>

    var searchCallMade = false;

    function searchAjaxBegin() {
        if (searchCallMade) {
            console.log('Will not proceed with AJAX call');
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(function () {

        $("#btn-search").trigger("click");
        searchCallMade = true;

    })

</script>
```